# Swift can't show back button after hiding it

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, xcode6

I have a UITableViewController with static cell that has a custom back button. I hide the back button in viewDidLoad with the code:

```
var cancelBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "closeSettings")
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelBtn
```

If I don't have the self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true line in place, the back button arrow still appears. With that line in the code, the back button is hidden and the Cancel button appears exactly how I want. The problem is coming when I open another view controller from a cell, the back button is not present. I instantiate the view controller when a cell is clicked, and use the Navigation Controller to push the View Controller. I have attempted to put

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false
```

in the code right before pushViewController(). When I do that I see the back button appear, but when the new View Controller is pushed on the Navigation Controller, the back button disappears.

I have even attempted putting the hidesBackButton = false line in the target View Controller's viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear, but I was not able to get the back button to appear. Could anyone help steer me in the right direction on what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try setting  `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false` at `viewWillDisappear()`?

Comment: I did try that and unfortunately it did not solve the problem.

One strange behavior to note is when I click on the cell to open the next View Controller (which is a UITableViewController), the back button is gone. Clicking on a cell closes the TableViewController and it returns nicely to the previous. When I click on the same cell to open the View Controller for a second time, the back button is now visible. Would anyone know what could cause this behavior?

Comment: That's because you are using viewDidLoad(). Research the difference between ViewDidAppear and viewDidLoad().

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for steering me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this setting

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false
```

on the destination view controller in the ViewWillAppear section.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. Sorry I did forget to mention this is in the Detail View of a UISplitViewController.